# Counting the words in a textarea

Tags: javascript, strings, regex

I've two working ways to do so, but which one should I use?

Common part: `var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");`

First way:

```
function updateStatusBar() {
    var text = textarea.value;
    statusBar.value = "Words: " + (text ? text.match(/\b\S+\b/g).length : "0") +
      "  Characters: " + text.replace(/\s/g, "").length +
      " / " + text.replace(/\n/g, "").length;
}
```

and second way:

```
function updateStatusBar() {
    var text = textarea.value;
    statusBar.value = "Words: " + (text.split(/\b\S+\b/).length - 1) +
      "  Characters: " + text.replace(/\s/g, "").length +
      " / " + text.replace(/\n/g, "").length;
}
```

Please review the `Words:` counting code. Which one should I use?

Comment: I would strongly recommend you, to count your characters by using something like: `textarea.innerText.length`

Comment: newlines aren't characters.

Comment: note that if you are doing this for textarea input validation, there is a native character counter in HTML5. Granted, characters aren't necessarily words. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key difference between the two approaches is essentially these lines,
counting the words in `text`:

```
text ? text.match(/\b\S+\b/g).length : "0"
// ... versus ...
text.split(/\b\S+\b/).length - 1
```

First of all, the first expression will crash for a non-empty text without words, for example `:!@#$`. Because a non-empty text is "true", but the `.match` will return null, so you'll get a null pointer exception in `.length`.

Secondly, I suggest a simpler and more intuitive regular expression to match words:

```
/\w+/g
```

That is, match a non-empty sequence of *word characters*.

You could use this as `text.match(/\w+/g)` (notice the "g" flag) or as `text.split(/\w+/)`. When using `match`, you need to check if the result is `null` or not, as you already did.

As for which way is better, using `match` or `split`,
I would argue for `match`:

- It's more intuitive: it matches the character sequences you're interested in, and then count the occurrences.
- It's probably more efficient: splitting implies creating an array of the results, but if you only need the size of the array (the count of elements), then it sounds like a waste.

Comment: `I want a solution.` returns "2 words", i.e. it don't work. See https://codepen.io/rhroyston/pen/ebrveB. I came up with the answer below. ...It boiled down to handling multiple spaces, tabs, and end-of-sentence characters such as a period, `.`

Comment: @RonRoyston As I wrote, I intentionally excluded words that would be single-letter. So getting 2 words for "I want a solution." is no surprise. This is a very old post, and I don't remember anymore why I wanted to exclude such words. I rewrote it now, thanks for bringing this to my attention.

Comment: honestly, that \W\w+, or whatever regex you originally had was quite a stunner to me. Very nice. Simple always wins. ...however, a word counter has gotta account for words and ignore characters that are not words. ...in any case, appreciate the input.

Answer (score 1):

A few comments on this...

*What is a character?* In your code, you are only counting non-spaces as characters. But, if the user enters `a        a` that counts as 10 characters to me.....

From my perspective, Characters can just be `text.length`.

Still your definition appears to be 'non-space characters'. Using that definition....

Now, about the regex. You describe 2 ways to count words, and one way to count non-space characters, and then, for some odd reason, you count newlines as well.

So, if I were to suggest that the best way to do it was with just one big, and few small regex... ? The big regex is the most complicated to run because it needs to do more complicated matching on a larger value. By stripping the value sooner, you can make it faster.

Note, you do not need the `\b` word boundary markers when dealing with either `\s+` or `\S+`.

```
//Function declaration, will be hoisted for 'addEventListener'
//Most of the work is done to have this work for multiple text area's
function updateStatus(){

  var text = this.value,
      // replace all words with an x
      xWords = text.replace(/\S+/g, "x"),
      //Replace those x's
      noWords = xWords.replace(/x/g, ""),
      //Get rid of newlines from just the spaces.
      noNewLines = noWords.replace(/\n/g, "");
  //You could consider a template function here..
  statusBar.textContent = "Length: " + text.length +
                          " Words: " + (xWords.length - noWords.length) +
                          " Characters: " + (text.length - noWords.length) +
                          " / " + (noWords.length - noNewLines.length);  
}
```

The above creates successively smaller string values, and compares the difference in length to compute the result....

Sometimes Plan C is the better option.

With the help of Konijn we/I have put together this jsfiddle [which shows it in operation](http://jsfiddle.net/RD49Y/).

Comment: `newline` is not a character and `.` is not a word (put a `.` on a new line).

Answer (score 1):

1. Replace `tab` and `newline` and sentence ending characters, e.g. `.`, with `space` character.
2. Split the resulting string on `space` character.
3. `.trim()` each item and `.push` to new array if it is not an empty string.

The `.length` of that new array provides your word count. See it in action here/below (test by adding several spaces between words and by using several line breaks):

```js
document.querySelector("textarea").addEventListener('keyup', count);

function count(){
  var resultArray = [];
  var str = this.value.replace(/[\t\n\r\.\?\!]/gm,' ');
  var wordArray = str.split(" ");
  for (var i = 0; i < wordArray.length; i++) {
    var item = wordArray[i].trim();
    if(item.length > 0){
      resultArray.push(item);
    }
  }
  document.querySelector("span").innerText = resultArray.length;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="8" cols="40"></textarea>
<p><span>0</span> words.</p>
```